# update angular from 6.1 to 8.2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, upgrade

While updating from angular 6 to 8, I am getting following messages.

ng -v gives following,

> node 12.16.1
>   angular 6.1.2
>   typescript 3.6.4

I am running command, ng update @angular/cli@8  @angular/core@8

```
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed.
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed.
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
              Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires 
"^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
              Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" 
(requires "^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
              Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires 
"^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
              Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser- 
dynamic" (requires "^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
              Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" 
(requires ">=3.4 <3.6", would install "3.6.4")
```

Comment: Moving across multiple major versions is not recommended. Instead I would recommend updating to every major release until you get to the one you want. So in your case on first place update to `Angular v7.0` and then to `Angular v8.0`. You can also use this [Angular update page](https://update.angular.io/).

Comment: To solve the issue you are describing. Try to uninstall or update codelyzer package, because it's using `@angular` packages. This should solve the `"codelyzer part of error"`.

Comment: Ok.. I will try to update

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 6 to Angular 9, I try:

```sh
@angular/cli@7 @angular/core@7
npm audit fix
npm i @angular/forms@9.1.9
npm i @angular/platform-browser@9.1.9
npm i @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.9
npm i @angular/core@9.1.9
npm i @angular/compiler@9.1.9
npm i @angular/common@9.1.9

@angular/cli @angular/core
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.